# Mute all other programs except mine whilst button is pressed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, audio, mute

I want to be able to mute all other programs and play a constant tone/sound while a button is held down.

The tone/sound is attached as a recouce under `My.Recources` and is called `Beep_effect`.

Most of the code is from one of the answers but is still does not work.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Imports CSCore
Imports CSCore.Codecs
Imports CSCore.CoreAudioAPI
Imports CSCore.SoundOut
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    Private filename As Object = My.Resources.Beep_effect
    Private _waveSource As IWaveSource
    Private _soundOut As ISoundOut
    Private device As MMDevice

    Sub Main()

        Using mmdeviceEnumerator = New MMDeviceEnumerator()
            Using mmdeviceCollection = mmdeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active)
                device = mmdeviceCollection.First
            End Using
        End Using

        _waveSource = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(filename).ToSampleSource().ToMono().ToWaveSource()
        _soundOut = New WasapiOut(False, AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, 100) With {.device = device}
        _soundOut.Initialize(_waveSource)
        _soundOut.Play()

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Main



    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

    Const WM_APPCOMMAND As UInteger = &H319
    Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As UInteger = &H8

    Private Sub Beep_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Beep.MouseDown
        Call Module1.Main()
        'My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Beep_effect, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Beep_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Beep.MouseUp
        'My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Silence_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Silence.MouseDown
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H200EB0, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE * &H10000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Silence_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Silence.MouseUp
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H200EB0, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE * &H10000)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you have any other questions just ask!

Comment: Well that only plays a file, what have ypu tried to mute others?

Comment: @Codexer I don't understand what you mean? What others?

Comment: What I mean is, ***you are only showing code to play a music file, not mute any other programs***. Please show an attempt at what you want to achieve and where it is failing, we help with specific issues.

Comment: @Codexer OK so what I want it to do is mute all the other programs and then play this file while the button is held down and when it releases the audio stops playing and the volume returns to its previous state. I don't know how to do this and after extensive googling the below comment is all that i could finds on the issue:

Comment: So after some more research I discovered [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/0b4d2919-1b48-4f55-8120-cedd22bea0c5/how-to-programmatically-mute-volume-of-selected-app-in-volume-mixer-windows-7?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment), [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316773(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940517(v=vs.85).aspx) but this dosnt exactly answer my question and I'm struggling to understand it.

Comment: `Private filename As Object = My.Resources.Beep_effect` the `filename` should be a `String`, path to file on your disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CSCore/) and `AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive` :

```
Imports CSCore
Imports CSCore.Codecs
Imports CSCore.CoreAudioAPI
Imports CSCore.SoundOut

Module Module1

    Private filename As String = "your.mp3"
    Private _waveSource As IWaveSource
    Private _soundOut As ISoundOut
    Private device As MMDevice

    Sub Main()

        Using mmdeviceEnumerator = New MMDeviceEnumerator()
            Using mmdeviceCollection = mmdeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active)
                device = mmdeviceCollection.First
            End Using
        End Using

        _waveSource = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(filename).ToSampleSource().ToMono().ToWaveSource()
        _soundOut = New WasapiOut(False, AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, 100) With {.Device = device}
        _soundOut.Initialize(_waveSource)
        _soundOut.Play()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks very complete and thorough. Only I'm struggling to understand how it fits into the code that i presented in the question. Please could you explain?

Comment: I have updated the post to show all the code I have so far but I cant seem to get it to work. I installed the package and inserted the code but it sill doesn't work got any other suggestions?

Comment: @T54 Are you sure you added more code to your post?

Comment: Yeah sorry I made the comment before I added the code. Also I had to make file name an object rather than a string to account for relative file paths.

Comment: @T54 The filename should be a String, path to file on your disk.